# Custom path parameter parsing drf-yasg and Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I'm trying to force `dry-yasg` to properly parse parameters from path. Let's say we have

```
path('users/<int:user_id>/', whatever.as_view(...))
```

In swagger docs it is not treated as `int`, but `string` instead

[image]

I have used

```
swagger_auto_schema(manual_parameters = [
openapi.Parameter(
        name,
        openapi.IN_PATH,
        description=desc,
        type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER,
        required=True
    )
]
```

but it's pretty annoying. I could not find a function/method/class responsible for parsing that.  Is there a simple method to change behaviour of this parser based on path, so that if `int` occurs then `openapi.TYPE_INTEGER` will be returned instead of `string`?

Comment: Your anwser helped me fix another problem I was having .. thank you. In the future, try to add the imports to your files to help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[drf-yasg](/questions/tagged/drf-yasg) determines the parameter type automatically [in some situations](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/blob/9ccf24c27ad46db4f566170553d49d687b6d21d6/src/drf_yasg/generators.py#L502), and falls back on string if detection fails.

```py
queryset = get_queryset_from_view(view_cls)

for variable in sorted(uritemplate.variables(path)):
    model, model_field = get_queryset_field(queryset, variable)
    attrs = get_basic_type_info(model_field) or {'type': openapi.TYPE_STRING}
```

As you can see, it tries to get type based on column type of view queryset. If your parameter name doesn't match anything in the queryset though, you get a string. So your first choice should be to try use a name it can autodetect.

If that doesn't work however, you will need to subclass `EndpointEnumerator` and override `get_path_parameters()`, probably easiest to call `super().get_path_parameters()` and go though each parameter and replace type based on variable name.

To use this class you will need [your own `OpenAPISchemaGenerator`](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/458#issuecomment-535919387).

> - use a custom OpenAPISchemaGenerator
> - override its endpoint_enumerator_class with your own EndpointEnumerator

Comment: This is quite interesting info. Thanks for that! Does not solve my problem though, as `path` is already in form `path/{user_id}`, not `path/<int:user_id>`.

Comment: Then you can try pre processing the args in the path by extracting your type information into `{"user_id": :"int"}`, replacing all the names in the path with name without type, calling `super()`, then post processing the output by setting the type on each based on the data you extracted ahead of time.